# how to modify existing roles in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created roles in mysql.

i would like to give one more privilege to existing role? How can i do?

Ex:

```
mysql> show grants for 'testing_users'@'localhost' using app_write;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for testing_users@localhost                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `testing_users`@`localhost`                         |
| GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `app_db`.* TO `testing_users`@`localhost` |
| GRANT `app_write`@`%` TO `testing_users`@`localhost`                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to add select privilege to the 'app_write' existing role

Answer (score 1):

GRANT SELECT ON
`app_db`.*
TO app_write;

Answer (score 1):

You have even examples in your question.

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `app_db`.* TO `testing_users`@`localhost`
```

For your case

```
GRANT SELECT ON `app_db`.* TO `app_write`
```

[Documentation MySQL 5.7 GRANT Statement](http://ttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

[Documentation MySQL 8.0 GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Just to complete question. If you want to remove permissions you use statement `REVOKE`.

```
REVOKE SELECT ON `app_db`.* FROM `app_write`
```